# LDAP search Unprocessed Continuation Reference(s)

Tags: grails, active-directory, ldap, referrals

I am using Grails 2, Groovy 1.8.5, Grails Ldap plugin to perform lookups via LDAP on Active Directory and I am getting javax.naming.PartialResultException: Unprocessed Continuation Reference(s); remaining name '/'. For authorization I use Spring LDAP which works fine with no problems.
I have looked around and most threads are talking about automatically following referrals which I use this flag for derefLinkFlag = true
I have even tried to pass this argument to JVM -Djava.naming.referral=follow

Has anyone come across this? Any suggestions are welcomed. Do you think it is something related to how AD is set up and if yes, what should I look for, I am new to AD.

I can avoid this exception because it happens my Active Directory to be Global Catalog, so I just connect to port 3268 and everything works fine. However, there is a caveat, not all attributes are added to Global Catalog, such as physicalDeliveryOfficeName. Which is also something that can be solved by replicating/including the attribute to GC schema, but it is something I do not wish to do for a number of reasons.

The code follows: 
The config

```
ldap {
  directories {
   rootdir {
    url = "ldap://my.company.com:389"
    base = "DC=my,DC=company,DC=com"
    userDn = "cn=User Name,cn=Users,dc=my,dc=company,dc=com"
    password = "secret"
    searchControls {
    countLimit = 400
    timeLimit = 6000
    searchScope = "subtree"
    derefLinkFlag = true
    }
  }
}

schemas = [
   com.mycompany.ldap.User,
   com.mycompany.ldap.Group
]
}
```

The domain

```
@GldapoSchemaFilter("(objectclass=person)")
class User {
@GldapoNamingAttribute
String cn

String dn
String mail
String sn
String physicalDeliveryOfficeName
}
```

The Controller

```
 class UserController {

   def index() {
        redirect(action: "list")
   }

   def list(){
    List users = User.findAll()
    [userInstanceList: users, userInstanceTotal: users.size()]
   }
 }
```

The exception:

```
Unprocessed Continuation Reference(s). Stacktrace follows:
javax.naming.PartialResultException: Unprocessed Continuation Reference(s); remaining      name '/'
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2846)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2820)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapNamingEnumeration.getNextBatch(LdapNamingEnumeration.java:129)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapNamingEnumeration.hasMoreImpl(LdapNamingEnumeration.java:198)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapNamingEnumeration.hasMore(LdapNamingEnumeration.java:171)
at gldapo.GldapoDirectory.nonPagedSearch(GldapoDirectory.groovy:162)
at gldapo.GldapoDirectory.search(GldapoDirectory.groovy:144)
at gldapo.schema.GldapoSchemaClassInjecto$__clinit__closure35.doCall(GldapoSchemaClassInjecto.groovy:374)
at gldapo.schema.GldapoSchemaClassInjecto$__clinit__closure38.doCall(GldapoSchemaClassInjecto.groovy:390)
at uk.co.mycomp.myapp.ldap.UserController.list(UserController.groovy:15)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Many thanks,
G

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to include the following line to your ldap settings in `Config.groovy`

```
ignorePartialResultExcepton = true
```

Comment: ignorePartialResultException is missing the i. Embarrassingly this caught me out.

Answer (score 2):

Naming exception javax.naming.PartialResultException: Unprocessed Continuation Reference(s); remaining name:
This error comes where you searchbaseDN works from top level.Use ou(Organization unit) in search base dn